# "Given the overhead"

Tags: tense

It seems that "Given the overhead" is the common pattern in the sentences.
In my understanding, it likely means "take too much costs to ...". But I'm afraid of misunderstanding, and look for more detailed explanation. I even can't understand the grammar of sentences which comes from googling, how to explain the "given" below:

1.

> ... Find the lowest cost schedule of the following project given the
>   overhead expenses as Rs.45,000/- per day. ...

2.

> ...  Feature decorrelation is an alternative for using the full
>   capacity of the models but the overfitting reduction margins are too
>   narrow given the overhead it introduces.  ...

Comment: *It is not **give** the overhead expenses*, but *given the overhead expenses*, which means *because  of the overhead expenses*. ***Given***: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/given

Comment: @user5768790 Thanks! I would like to accept your answer if possible.

Answer (score 2):

"Overhead" is business jargon for what economists call fixed costs. These are expenses that, at least in the short term, do not vary with the amount of goods or services sold. For example, rent on facilities, many types of insurance, utilities such as gas and electricity, wages of superintendence, and long term equipment leases are examples of expenses that are incurred even if no goods are sold.

A frequently useful way to think about the success or failure of a business is to multiply the difference between the sales price and the direct cost per unit sold (the primary direct costs usually being for labor and materials), the so-called margin in business jargon, times the number of units sold. If the product of volume and margin exceeds overhead, the business succeeds. If the overhead exceeds the product of volume and margin, the business fails.

If a business with high overhead is to succeed, it must have a high volumes of sales or a wide margin (or both).

Comment: I think the question is not  about the meaning of  overheads.